# Prompt response "I didn't understand" when user input is 3 or less characters

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

This dialog prompts a user for an acronym to be searched in a JavaScript Object. When the user input is less than 4 characters the bot returns:

> "I didn't understand. Please try again."

When I provide an acronym that is 4 or more characters the dialog works perfectly. Is there a lower bound for the number of characters in a user response?

```
bot.dialog('AcronymDialog', [ 
    function (session, arg) {
    // Prompts user for an acronym to be searched in an object
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please provide the Industry Acronym you wish to be translated.");
 },
    function(session, results) {
        //If response is 4 or more characters this is executed
        session.send(industryAcronyms[results.response]);
    }
]);
```

Additionally,  even if the code in the results function is session.send("Hello, World"); and it never searches the JS objects the response is "I didn't understand. Please try again."

[image]

[image]

Comment: where did you end dialog?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error.  It works fine for me using this code:
`bot.dialog('/', [ 
    function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "Please provide the Industry Acronym you wish to be translated.");
 },
    function(session, results) {
        session.send('You picked: ' + results.response);
    }
])`

Comment: what version of the sdk are u using?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I am running off of the Azure Bot Services so I assume that is the current build.

Comment: @NilsW I tried my code out in the emulator and my code works properly just like your code. What makes this different in the Azure Bot Services? I will try again in a Skype Channel but I expect the same result as Azure.

Comment: If you continue to have problems, please open a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder/issues/new